# What known toxin(s) would fit the scenario of the alleged/reported Kim Jong-Nam poisoning?

Tags: toxicology

According to the news reports:

- Substance administered to the face (presumed inhaled or swallowed)
- Small dose (apparently)
- Lethal within a couple of hours
- No reports of any effect on assailant or bystanders (presumably not airborne or harmful by skin contact alone).

What (if any) known toxin(s) fit the above profile?

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd call this opinion-based, but it certainly lacks a notable claim and thus is off-topic for this site.  Our questions are generally "Is this true?"  Or "Is there a scientific study supporting this?"  This is more "How would this work?"  I don't know that there is a poison stack, but I'm quite sure that this isn't it.

Comment: They found traces of VX in tissue samples of his face and eyes. See, the facts don't even fit your profile (point 1 and especially 4). Which is why it doesn't help to speculate. ;-)

Comment: AFAIK, Malaysia has said today that VX nerve agent was used in the attack. VX is listed by the UN as a weapon of mass destruction.